# Can't login sites using Selenium Webdriver (Node JS)

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So that's it, I can do everything but login in my account on sites.
For example, here I am trying to login Nike website, but I am taking this error:

We are unable to connect to our servers right now. Please try again later.
GENERIC "0 - POST request to https://unite.nike.com/login blocked"

This does also happen in other webpages where I try to login with an account, so I don't think is a code error, may it be that Selenium can get blocked from login sites?

Code:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, Until} = require ('selenium-webdriver')
const config = require(`./config.json`);

function sleep (ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function talla1() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    driver.manage().window().maximize() 
    await driver.get(`${config.loginlink}`);
    await sleep(6000);
    await driver.findElement(By.id('hf_cookie_text_cookieAccept')).click();
    await sleep (500)
    await driver.findElement(By.name('emailAddress')).sendKeys(`${config.email}`);
    await sleep (300)
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath('password')).sendKeys(`${config.contraseña}`);
}
```

** Have a separate folder where I already consted the email, password and link of the page.

** Nike login page is https://www.nike.com/login, which I can login from my own browser but not with the Selenium opened one.

** No, I am not getting ip blocked, I can still login with a normal Chrome browser.

** Tried login Google with Selenium browser and error displayed saying that the browser isn't secure.

Comment: I can try this in Python and Selenium, let me know if you are open for that

Comment: @cruisepandey yes, please, Ill try to replicate it on js.